# Creating a GdkPixbuf from raw Bitmap data

Tags: c, bitmap, gdk, gdkpixbuf

I am trying to port a [Clean](http://clean.cs.ru.nl) graphics library (specifically, ObjectIO) to Linux with GDK. The library consists of a non-OS-specific part, which I don't want to touch because of compatibility issues, and an OS-specific part which I can touch.

One of the functions I have to implement is one that takes raw data from a .bmp file and has to build a `GdkPixbuf` from this. This function has to be written in C.

I am aware of the function `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file()`, but I do not get the file name (and can't change that, as it's in the non-OS-specific part of the library). I only get the raw data.

I saw [this manual entry](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Image-Data-in-Memory.html), and I guess I could use `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data()`, but this requires that you know the *row stride* of the image, of which I'm unsure how to get it.

Is there a way to get the row stride from the file? If not, the only possibility I see is to create a temporary file with the data and then call `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file()` - but that would be really ugly.

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if the row stride was always equal to the width.

Comment: @icktoofay at first, I thought width * 3 (you need three bytes for a 24-bit image), but that doesn't show good results yet. I also tried numbers around that. It doesn't seem to be that simple, unfortunately ...

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the function:

```
int stride = cairo_format_stride_for_width(CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, ImageWidth);
```